# str_extract_all not working with regex, R

Tags: r, regex, string

I´m trying this

```
string  <- ":  FC Relacionado con Paciente  FC Protocolo1  FC Comunicacion entre Profesionales1  FC Disponibilidad"


str_extract_all(string, "FC.*1")
```

It gives back this result:

```
[1] "FC Relacionado con Paciente  FC Protocolo1  FC Comunicacion entre Profesionales1"
```

What I want is this:

```
[1] FC Protocolo1  FC Comunicacion entre Profesionales1"
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
string  <- ":  FC Relacionado con Paciente  FC Protocolo1  FC Comunicacion entre Profesionales1  FC Disponibilidad"
str_extract_all(string, "\\bFC\\b(?:(?!\\bFC\\b).)*?1")
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/W5FBZY). Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "FC Protocolo1"                       
[2] "FC Comunicacion entre Profesionales1"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nqji27/1). **Note**: if there must be no digit/letter/underscore after `1`, add another `\b` there.

*Pattern details*

- `\bFC\b` - a whole word `FC`
- `(?:(?!\bFC\b).)*?` - any single char other than line break chars (if you need to match across line breaks, add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern), zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that does not start a whole word `FC` char sequence
- `1` - a `1` char.

Comment: Always learn a lot from your regex answers, +1!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_split` and `str_detect` as follows

```
s <- str_split(gsub('(FC)', '_\\1', string), '_')[[1]]

s[str_detect(s, 'FC.*1')]
```

Output

```
[1] "FC Protocolo1  "                       
[2] "FC Comunicacion entre Profesionales1  "
```

If the string is in a variable of a tibble with name `string` you can use

```
s <- str_split(gsub('(FC)', '_\\1', string), '_')

new_column <- sapply(s, \(x) paste0(x[str_detect(x, 'FC.*1')], collapse = ''))
```

Comment: See the above update .

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be `grep` + `strsplit` (but I would say my solution is not as advanced or efficient as [@Wiktor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75885981/12158757))

```
> grep("FC.*1", strsplit(string, "\\s+(?=FC)", perl = TRUE)[[1]], value = TRUE)
[1] "FC Protocolo1"
[2] "FC Comunicacion entre Profesionales1"
```